# How to fetch text strings in regex in the format (A(B(C)))

Tags: regex

I already know regex is not fully suitable to extract info which is recursively nested, but this pattern won't go deeper, thus I wonder if simple regex can do the job.

How do I extract then `some text A`, `some text B` and `some text C` if they are in the format

```
some text A ( some text B ( some text C))
```

Please mind that in some cases may be only

```
some text A ( some text B)
```

Comment: Have you tried [`\b[^()]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/M9MUk2/2)?

Comment: Is `some text A ( some text B ( some text C) finish text B) finish text A` possible? FYI, you are either missing an opening parenthesis or have one too many closing parenthesis; not sure if this is intentional.

Comment: What about `some text A (( some text C))`?

Comment: Are you looking to validate that the text is in that format too? So `some text A` should be ignored? The comment by @Alireza is  good but it won't validate that you're dealing with the format you've described.

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no not possible

Comment: Well, that answers **one** of my three questions...

Comment: @Wiktor Javascript

Comment: @MonkeyZeus sorry, I didn't see other questions. `some text A ((some text C))` is not possible. It's really only the two options you see on the original question. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Alireza that considers also the second option `some text A (some text B))`?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Yes.

Comment: @Alireza you're a genius, please do kindly reply it as an answer such that I can set it as the correct answer

Comment: @Alireza you're a genius, please do kindly reply it as an answer such that I can set it as the correct answer

Comment: Another workaround pattern here is [`\w[\w\s]*`](https://regex101.com/r/isJI93/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `\b[^()]+\b`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AVHk4C/1)

**Explanation**

- `\b` is [`word boundary`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html)
- `[^()]+` match anything one or more times except "(" and ")"

Comment: Just a question, if strings may have space characters, why do you use word boundary? I don't get that part. I know it works, but can't understand why

Comment: The `[^()]+` part match space and all other characters except "(" and ")", word boundary matches positions where one side is a word character and the other side is not a word character. See [this](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html) for more reading.